# Why does the following expression in z3 take a long time?

Tags: z3

What is wrong with this z3 expression?

```
(declare-const arg_1 Int)
(assert
  (and
     (not (= 0 (mod arg_1 10)))
     (= 0 (mod (+ 1 arg_1) 10))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Trying to evaluate it with `z3` hangs for ever. On the other hand, if I try either of the below, it returns immediately.

> Using the first expression only

```
(declare-const arg_1 Int)
(assert (not (= 0 (mod arg_1 10))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)

=> sat
(model 
  (define-fun arg_1 () Int
 1)
)
```

> Using the second expression only

```
(declare-const arg_1 Int)
(assert (= 0 (mod (+ 1 arg_1) 10)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)

=> sat
(model
  (define-fun arg_1 () Int
    9)
)
```

Asserting them together in the same file also returns immediately.

```
(declare-const arg_1 Int)
(declare-const arg_2 Int)
(assert (= 0 (mod (+ 1 arg_1) 10)))
(assert (not (= 0 (mod arg_2 10))))

;(assert (= arg_1 arg_2))
(check-sat)
(get-model)

=> sat
(model 
  (define-fun arg_2 () Int
    1)
  (define-fun arg_1 () Int
    9)
)
```

However, if I uncomment the `arg_1 = arg_2` assertion, it will hang.

Comment: What happens if you assert them separately but in the same file?

Comment: @LeventErkok updated with the result. It returns immediately unless I try to assert both variables are equal.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a z3 bug. If you run the original with `z3 -v:3`, you get:

```
$ z3 -v:3 a.smt2
(smt.searching)
(smt.simplifying-clause-set :num-deleted-clauses 1)
final-check OPTIMAL
final-check OPTIMAL
...
```

and it keeps printing that. I tried with cvc4, yices, and mathsat; and they all solve it immediately. You should report this at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues so they can take a look at it.